# Is there an analysis of the creation of axioms for a mathematical structure as a computational problem?

Tags: algorithms, computability, logic, search-problem

Historically, what has happened is the following:

1. There is a "mechanical" structure, most importantly, arithmetic, which operates according to a set of well-defined rules that a stupid computer can easily follow. e.g. a computer can easily calculate $5349\cdot 5345=...$
2. There is a "mechanical" proof-system, most importantly, first order logic, which *also* operates according to well-defined rules that a stupid computer can follow. e.g. a computer can easily apply derivation rules to go from $\forall x \phi(x)$ to $\exists x \phi(x)$, etc.
3. Then there is a non-mechanical "creative" human, who uses his badly-understood "natural insight" to formulate a set of "axioms about arithmetic", which are words in (2)'s language "about" the operations of (1)'s arithmetic computations. He also formulates a set of "logical axioms", the rules by which the mechanical proof system should operate. He chooses these rules because his intuitive insight says that they are "obviously correct".

It seems to me that this third element in the chain (though it happens first chronologically), is always done in an ad-hoc way. But the fact that this has always been done this way so far, doesn't mean that it necessarily has to be this way.

**My question is:** Has there been an analysis of the creation of axioms **as a computational problem**? That is, of the problem of choosing axioms about some mathematical structure, for use in a logic-language?

This computational problem is essentially: given e.g. the rules of arithmetic, find a first-order statement that we can use as an axiom to then derive further properties.

ps. I know that this is a vague question. I am simply asking whether someone has analysed this problem in some way.

Comment: What sort of requirements do you have for 'axiom creation'? Do you want to minimize the number of axioms? Select axioms from a big list? I'm not sure how you think such a task should be evaluated, which is required if you want to phrase the task as a computational problem.

Comment: @discretelizard, I'm sure you know how people evaluate whether their axiomatization is good or not: 1. Are the axioms true in the desired structure. 2 do they imply a large amount of other true statements. 3. Are they compact.

Comment: Well, I can't read minds, now can I. Aren't axioms true by definition? So why have point 1? Furthermore, a 'large amount' is rather imprecise, as is "compactness" (I think?) in this case. 

Anyway, I agree with you that it is vague. I think the only answer that would work here would be one providing literature on this, if such literature exists. Perhaps you should specify that further.

Comment: @discretelizard. Sorry, I shouldn't have suggested you could have read my mind. To answer your question: An axiom is not true by definition. An axiom is true by virtue of the characteristics of the underlying mathematical structure. E.g. arithmetic is basically defined by a set of rules of how to do operations on numbers (addition, multiplication). but yeah the only real answer would be one that points to some literature. I don't know anything about that literature so I'm gonna leave it open to whomever knows more about this.

Comment: Where did you get your definition of 'axiom'? I've never seen a definition or usage of 'axiom' such that it isn't 'true' by definition.

Comment: @discretelizard, take a mathematical struxture X that is not a group. Then group axioms are not true in X. In this way, the group axioms are not by definition true, but are true or false for a particular structure depending on what that structure is. So you actually have to check for that particular structure whether it is true or not. You can't just "define" it to be true for that structure. Of course you can define the group axioms to be true for "groups", but then you are not starting out with a structure.

Comment: "Then group axioms are not true in X" This is a nonsensical statement. The group axioms simply aren't applicable to structures that aren't groups. I don't understand your usage of axiom. At the very least, your definition is different from various sources: https://www.britannica.com/topic/axiom , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom , https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/axiom .
So, I'm not sure if what you're really looking for.

Comment: @discretelizard, I think you're wrong, but let's just for the moment agree to disagree, and wait until someone comes with an answer.

Comment: Yes, this discussion doesn't seem to be going anywhere, but be aware that others may share my confusion.

Comment: "This computational problem is essentially: given e.g. the rules of arithmetic, find a first-order statement that we can use as an axiom to then derive further properties." For example, given a set of axioms, compute a Gödel sentence for them and add it to that set of axioms?

Comment: @ALbertHendriks yes that would be one part of it, but I think a very narrow one. The more interesting question is to find those original axioms in the first place. Like, if you want to find axioms for standard arithmetic, how do you find them? Certainly a computer can dismiss certain axioms immediately, such as  $\forall x 0=x$, simply by checking for $x=1$ whether $x=0$ and finding that its wrong. But that aplroach is not always possible.

Comment: That is only false because of other axioms that imply $1\neq 0$. In fact the axiom $\forall x 0=x$ is very well possible, just not in combination with specific other axioms.

Comment: @AlbertHendrik, I disagree. It is not false because other axioms imply its negation. It's false because if you take a collection of one rock and a collection of zero rocks, and then count them, you will not count the same amount. Alternatively, it is because if you store the number 0 in a byte in a computer, and the number 1 in another one, and then check if they are bitwise identical, this check will give you "FALSE". Your definition of "truth" as something that "follows from axioms" is deficient. In fact the whole concept of "semantics" vs "syntax" collapses with your definition.

Comment: That's your interpretation of 1 and 0 as being certain quantities. 1 and 0 are just symbols and different symbols may represent the same thing. See this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1437125/220116

Comment: @AlbertHendriks, no I was referring to the actual numbers $0$ and $1$, meaning the natural numbers, not the symbols in first order language. That's precisely the diatinction I was making. But let's just agree to disagree and wait till someone comes up with something. Though that probably wont happen now.